# Cursor value null

Tags: android

I am developing an app which gets outgoing SMS content through content resolver but it is giving some problems.  Please help me.

```
package com.company.cellSafetyZone.model;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class OutGoingSmsService extends Service
{   Context context;
    SmsObserver smsObserver;
    Cursor cursor;
    Handler handler=new  Handler();
    private String TAG="SMS SERVICE";
    boolean change;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public OutGoingSmsService() 
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"blank constructor");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public OutGoingSmsService(Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"context constructor");
        this.context=context;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {   Log.d(TAG,"in on Create() of sms service");
        super.onCreate();
        smsObserver=new SmsObserver(handler);
         Log.d(TAG,"calling service");
        startService();
    }
    private void startService()
    { Log.d(TAG,"registering resolver");
    cursor=this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), null,null,null,null);
        Log.d(TAG,"registering observer");
       cursor.registerContentObserver(smsObserver);
        Log.d(TAG,"registerd");
    }
    void setChangeValue(boolean selfChange)
    {System.out.println("in setChange");
        change=selfChange;
        if(change==false)
        {     try
{       cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), null,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            }catch (Exception e)
            {   System.out.println("in catch."+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String protocol=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
            Log.d(TAG,"protocol value."+protocol);
            if(protocol==null)
                onSmsSend();
            }}
    private void onSmsSend()
    { cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i <cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) 
        {String column=cursor.getColumnName(i);
            String msg=cursor.getString(i); }}}
```

It is calling observer and get back in this service again in `onSmsSend()` method.  But now giving an exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
atcom.company.cellSafetyZone.model.OutGoingSmsService.setChangeValue(OutGoingSmsService.java:104)
at com.company.cellSafetyZone.model.SmsObserver.onChange(SmsObserver.java:42)
at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:43)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is the cursor null?  There is a small thing which I am unable to catch so help me out please.

Comment: improve the post formatting please!

Comment: which android version are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print some log statements about what is inside the cursor before registering it. Like:

`Log.d(TAG, cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")));`

I'm asking you to do this because not all phones store the SMS data with that content provider. For whatever reason, there is no official way to get the SMS data, just that a lot of apps and manufacturers decided to settle on that.

Comment: Good, I'm glad.  If my answer solved the problem, please mark it as correct with the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any wrong programming in it as you are able to get cursor in other part but as you are getting null pointer exception I think you should add logs at each interval after cursor query and write cursor's column count so you can find any wrong code.

One thing I can suggest is to add cursor query again in your onsmsend function.